# Sending data from a boost asio client

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to write a program which can send data over a network to my Java server listening on a port.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void do_somenetwork(std::string host, int port, std::string message)
{
    std::array<char, 1024> _arr;
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host), port);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(ios);
    socket.connect(endpoint);

    boost::array<char, 128> buf;
    std::copy(message.begin(), message.end(), buf.begin());
    boost::system::error_code error;

    socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf, message.size()), error);

    socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_arr));
    std::cout.write(&_arr[0], 1024);

    socket.close();
}

int main(){
    do_somenetwork(std::string("127.0.0.1"), 50000, ";llsdfsdf");

    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
}
```

When I use this program I keep getting error message as below:

```
C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe -     this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 2132    1   ConsoleApplication1
```

I have tried the warning and not found any result related to this error. Is there a better way to write this code? I am really new to C++ and do not have much idea about how Boost is actually working.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 and boost 1.60.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the answer to your question but rather a workaround.

I think the error comes from the `std::copy` call, you could bypass it by using the [data](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) method from `std::string` directly as the buffer array instead of copying it in your `boost::array`.

Like this :

`socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(message.data(), message.size()), error);`

Comment: Thank you. This does solve my problem. I am new to stack overflow as well, should I accept this as a solution just because it solved my concern?

Comment: @masterconqueror Please refer to this [help topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers] as well as this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to read more about what to do in this case. And welcome to stack overflow :)